# How to start/restart workers remotely in celery?

Tags: celery, restart, worker

There is a cluster with different machines, and each of them has a proj code in a specified path (`~/celery_node/`). At the beginning, there is no running celery worker in the cluster.

Question #1:
 How can I start some celery workers on each machine without logging into any of them or just by logging into one and starting celery workers on other machines?

Question #2: If each machine already has some celery workers started, how can I restart them without logging in remotely?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) to carry out remote operations

```
from fabric.api import run

def host_type():
    run('service celery start')
```

Once a task is defined, it may be run on one or more servers, like so:

```
$ fab -H localhost,linuxbox restart celery
[localhost] run: service celery start
[localhost] out: celery started/running
[linuxbox] run: service celery start
[linuxbox] out: celery started/running

Done.
Disconnecting from localhost... done.
Disconnecting from linuxbox... done.
```

Comment: Thanks for your modification and answer. Fabric is a command-line tool for remote operations with SSH, but I want to know whether there are some solutions related to celery itself.

Answer (score 0):

Look into flower
https://github.com/mher/flower
It allows alot of those management type jobs

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've studied flower before, but it's not the right solution. First, we can't start a worker from flower which just monitors the started ones. Second, based on the remote control (broadcast), it can restart the **worker pool** but not really restart workers themselves. Third, when I start a worker with command `celery -A proj worker -l info` locally, flower just has the ability to monitor but even not **shut down** it.

Answer (score 0):

additionally there is the [autoreload](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#autoreloading) flag :

> Starting celery worker with the --autoreload option will enable the worker to watch for file system changes to all imported task modules imported (and also any non-task modules added to the CELERY_IMPORTS setting or the -I|--include option).
>
> This is an experimental feature intended for use in development only, using auto-reload in production is discouraged as the behavior of reloading a module in Python is undefined, and may cause hard to diagnose bugs and crashes. Celery uses the same approach as the auto-reloader found in e.g. the Django runserver command.